# Transforming XML time series to multi-column CSV

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an XML with multiple time series into a multi-column CSV.

Example XML:

```
<root>
  <series id='Series 1'>
    <datapoint>
      <date>01/01/1970</date>
      <value>123</value>
    </datapoint>
    <datapoint>
      <date>01/02/1970</date>
      <value>456</value>
    </datapoint>
  </series>
  <series id='Series 2'>
    <datapoint>
      <date>01/02/1970</date>
      <value>789</value>
    </datapoint>
    <datapoint>
      <date>01/03/1970</date>
      <value>ABC</value>
    </datapoint>
  </series>
</root>
```

Target CSV:

```
date|Series 1|Series 2
01/01/1970|123|
01/02/1970|456|789
01/03/1970||ABC
```

Current XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" kilns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match ="/root">  
        <xsl:for-each select='series'>
            <xsl:text>Date|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="datapoint"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match ="datapoint">   
        <xsl:value-of select="date"/><xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current issue is that the `for-each` is no longer executed if the `apply-templates` tag is present. Only the latter is called.

Any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a row for each distinct `date`, and in each row a cell for each `series`. In XSLT 1.0 this would be implemented as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="date" match="date" use="." />
<xsl:key name="datapoint" match="datapoint" use="concat(date, '|', ancestor::series/@id)" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="series" select="series" />
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <xsl:text>date</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$series">
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- DATA -->
    <!-- a row for each distinct date, using Muenchian grouping -->
    <xsl:for-each select="series/datapoint/date[count(. | key('date', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
        <!-- a cell for each series -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$series">
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('datapoint', concat($date, '|', @id))/value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Amazing! It works just like I hoped! I will have to study this a bit before I understand how it works. I may come back with questions if I get stuck... Many thanks for your help.